# Property mutation in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So I have a multiple codes like this:

```
<input id="data" type="text"  v-model="data">
<label for="data">Data</label>
```

And I tried to make a property out of it so that I won't repeat it every time:

```
Vue.component('textbox', {
  template: `
   <div>
   <input :id="id" type="text" v-model="value">
   <label :for="id">{{ label }}</label>
   </div>
  `,
  props: [
      "id", "value", "label", "for"],
  watch: {
    value: function(newVal){
       this.$emit('input', newVal)
    }
  }
})
```

and access it in my html like this:

```
<textbox v-model="data" id="someID" label="Data"></textbox>
```

Everything works fine but every time I type in the textbox I get this warning in the console:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value" 
(found in component <textbox>)
```

Is there a way to remove that warning message? Or am I doing it the wrong way? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error itself says Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value so instead of props try data or computed prop

Comment: @VinodLouis Would you mind giving me an example? I don't get it honestly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use watch at all. And instead of using v-model, try this:

```
<input :id="id" type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
```

working example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/dNQopR?editors=1010

Comment: That did it! Thank you.